# Foreach loop container issue in SSIS package VS 2017

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

Working on SSIS package in VS 2017, to extract data from excel files reside in  a folder with the help of foreach loop container. As conventional method, I tried to map file path variable in Foreach loop and use it in the Excel Connection manager. In SSDT 2017, it is asking me to have a  excel file path assigned to the variable all the time unlike visual studio 2010.

So configured package with variables as shown below.

### Foreach Loop Variable Mapping

- User::varFileName Index 0

### Package Variable

- varFileName = D\SSIS Referral Files\2019-11-01.DataSource.xlsx

### Excel Connection Manager Property

- ExcelFilePath = @[User::varFileName]

This is working fine.
Now I want to assign a project level parameter to variable "varFileName".
Assigned parameter to variable using Expression Builder, the value is not getting override by Foreach Loop, resulting in importing the same file multiple times until foreach loop iteration ends.
Is there any solution for this issue?

[image: Data flow task inside foreach loop]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how your Control Flow is designed? Where is your Expression Task in relation to the Loop? Why are you trying to assign the value from a project-level parameter and then trying to assign the value of Loop enumerator? What does the assignment expression look like?

Comment: should be your assign variable side have issue.